# Is this a compiler bug in MSVC++ 2017 update 3

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-bug

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int>::iterator foo();
void bar(void*) {}

int main()
{
    void* p;
    while (foo() != foo() && (p = 0, true))
    {
        bar(p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Results in error:

> c:\users\jessepepper\source\repos\testcode\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(15): error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'p' used

Comment: Upvoted, but can you give a slightly less convoluted and more motivating example?

Comment: What would you expect?

Comment: I don't see how the value of `p` could be accessed before it is initialized. Moreover on the version of MSVC on compiler explorer, the code just compile without error [link](https://godbolt.org/g/sqaSt6). Certainly a compiler bug.

Comment: The program is ill-formed since there's no body for `foo()`. Do you get the same warning for a correct program?

Comment: @M.M The compilation unit is perfectly well-formed, with a declaration of an external function. Whether the program as a whole is ill-formed depends on whatever other compilation units are part of the final program, but since compilation doesn't even get past this one, it is irrelevant.

Comment: @M.M it should certainly compile though, yet it doesn't.

Comment: User error. If you turn on extra unreliable warnings and turn them into errors, of course no code will compile...

Comment: Did not understand why you need this `while (foo() != foo() && (p = 0, true))`, especially `(p = 0, true)` part? To test a "trick" and make program less readable? Why not `!(p = 0)` instead of `(p = 0, true)`?

Comment: I'd say it's a bug, The code is perverse. `bar(nullptr);` would do. Why all the tomfoolery with initialising `p`?

Comment: @Pesixty - Assume he is dealing with legacy code. The tomfoolers may be long gone.

Comment: @SebastianRedl that depends on how the compiler was invoked. The other answer suggests it's coming from link-time optimization. It wouldn't be difficult to add a valid body and see if the error persists

Comment: @Persixty, this was a distillation of a problem found in a third party library.

Comment: @JessePepper Ouch. I've read the other comments and apparently it's suddenly turned into an Error that can't be disabled not a low priority warning (as was) that's the bug here. The short hop is to hack the code and initialize p. Though as I said, the code presented is perverse. In that version `p` is never dereferenced let alone potentially uninitialized so the code has no undefined behaviour and should compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some experimenting with VC++2017 Preview.

It's definitely a ***bug*** bug. It makes it impossible to compile and link code that might be correct, albetit smelly.

A warning would be acceptable. (See @SebastianRedl answer.) But in the latest and greatest VC++2017, it is being treated as an error, not warning, even with warnings turned off, and "Treat warnings as errors" set to No.   Something odd is happening. The "error" is being thrown late - after it says, "Generating code". I would guess, and it's only a guess, that the "Generating code" pass is doing global analysis to determine if un-initialized access is possible, and it's getting it wrong. Even then, you should be able to disable the error, IMO.

I do not know if this is new behavior. Reading Sebastian's answer, I presume it is. When I get any kind of warning at any level, I always fix it in the code, so I would not know.

Jesse, click on the triangular flag near the top right of Visual Studio, and report it.

Answer (score 6):

It's kind of a bug, but very typical for the kind of code you write.

First, this isn't an error, it's a warning. C4703 is a level 4 warning (meaning that it isn't even enabled by default). So in order to get it reported as an error (and thus interrupt compilation), compiler arguments or pragmas were passed to enable this warning and turn it into an error (`/W4` and `/Werror` are the most likely I think).

Then there's a trade-off in the compiler. How complex should the data flow analysis be to determine whether a variable is actually uninitialized? Should it be interprocedural? The more complex it is, the slower the compiler gets (and because of the halting problem, the issue may be undecidable anyway). The simpler it is, the more false positives you get because the condition that guarantees initialization is too complex for the compiler to understand.

In this case, I suspect that the compiler's analysis works as follows: the assignment to `p` is behind a conditional (it only happens if `foo() != foo()`). The usage of `p` is also behind a conditional (it only happens if that complex and-expression is true). The compiler cannot establish a relationship between these conditions (the analysis is not complex enough to realize that `foo() != foo()` is a precondition to the entire while loop condition being true). Thus, the compiler errs on the side of assuming that the access could happen without prior initialization and emits the warning.

So it's an engineering trade-off. You could report the bug, but if you do, I suggest you supply a more compelling real-world example of idiomatic code to argue in favor of making the analysis more complex. Are you sure you can't restructure your original code to make it more approachable to the compiler, and more readable for humans at the same time?

Comment: I take it back. It's a bug bug, because turning off all warnings does not save the day. It is now a hard error. `1>c:\users\dave\documents\vc++ 2017\projects\scratch\scratch.cpp(81): error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'p' used` Something odd is happening. The "error" is being generated late - perhaps while linking, or maybe duing whole-program optimization.

Comment: Ping.  It's def. broken. C4703 is reported as an error, not warning. It cannot be disabled. I don't know if this is new behavior or not.

Comment: @JiveDadson Huh, that's interesting. This warning isn't new; it's documented all the way back to [VS2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851030(v=vs.110).aspx). Best guess is they rewrote the analysis as part of their compiler refactoring and messed up. In that case, you should definitely report a bug.

Comment: I started to, but I decided it was easier to let Jesse do it.

Answer (score 1):

For sure it's a bug. I tried to remove it in all possible ways, including #pragma. The real thing is that this is reported as an error, not as a warning as Microsoft say. This is a big mistake from Microsoft. It's NOT a WARNING, it's an ERROR. Please, do not repeat again that it's a warning, because it's NOT.
What I'm doing is trying to compile some third party library whose sources I do not want to fix in any way, and should compile in normal cases, but it DOESN'T compile in VS2017 because the infamous "error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable *** used".
Someone found a solution for that?

Comment: Hi Rob, this appears to repeat what Jive Dadson wrote 5 months ago. You can't vote for his answer yet (as you're new here) but that's how you can indicate in the future that an  existing answer is correct.